# Laravel 4.2 : keep multidimensional array data in session

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, session, laravel-4.2

In my laravel 4.2 application, i want to store the cart item details in session.

```
cartId =>[
            0 => [
                productId => x,
                quantity  => y
            ],
            1 => [
                productId => u,
                quantity  => v
            ],
            2 => [
                productId => l,
                quantity  => m
            ]

         ]
```

I didn't found a way except this

```
Session::push('user.teams', 'developers');
```

for storing as array in session.
but the same is not applicable here

Comment: Try: `Session::put(<key>, json_encode($your_array));`

Comment: Yeah,Session::put($shoppingCartId, json_encode($array));
        $test = Session::get($shoppingCartId);
        $test1 = json_decode($test);
        dd($test1[0]->productId); solved to an extend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can insert the array directly in the session.

```
$someArray = ['name' => 'John Doe', 'username' => 'jdoe'];

Session::put('user', $someArray);
```

When you want to retrieve its value just need to:

```
$user = Session::get('user');
echo $user['name'] // output: John Doe
```

Same applicable for multidimensional array...

Answer (score 1):

You can just store the information in the key required, such as:

```
$cartDetails = [ 
                 0 => [
                       productId => x,
                       quantity  => y
                 ],
                 1 => [
                       productId => u,
                       quantity  => v
                 ],
                 2 => [
                       productId => l,
                       quantity  => m
                 ]
               ];

Session::put('cart', $cartDetails);
```

Each user will have it's own cart, can you can validate with `Session::has('cart')` and `Session::get('cart')` will get you the content of `$cartDetails`.

`Session::forget('cart')` will erase the key 'cart' from the Session, meaning `Session::has('cart')` == false and `Session::get('cart')` is null

If you plan on using key's as Id's (Something among the lines of Session::put($cartId, $cartDetails)), I wouldn't advise as later on, if you need to add something with the same logic, you will compromise the Session's key and possibly, overwrite it. Same applies if someone else takes a look at the code (or even you in a not-so-long future) and need to read the code, there isn't a clear perception of whats in the session unless you read the whole function. (IMO)

> https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/session